# Access function argument from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

How do I access version argument from within FetchData method below ?.

Note - Fetch data is an async Rest call which passes its data to callback function.

```
 function TestData(guid, version) {                    
            var data = '';
            data =  FetchData(guid, function (guid, msg) {
                    alert(version);
            return getData(guid, msg);      
            }));        
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just pass version in as an argument to FetchData?

Comment: What you have should work fine. JavaScript has lexical scope and `version` is clearly in the lexical scope of the callback. What is the problem? (I mean, there is a syntax error, maybe that's it? )

Comment: If you are not willing to stick around to clarify your question, then please don't ask a question at all.

Answer (score -1):

If you need it in the callback - this code is OK.

For example the result of this code will be alert('hello')

```
 function TestData(guid, version) {                    
        var data = '';
        data =  FetchData(guid, function (guid, msg) {
                alert(version);
        return getData(guid, msg);      
        });        
    }
function FetchData(guid, callback) {
     $.get('http://www.example.com/', callback);
}
TestData('abc', 'hello');
```

Comment: So you are saying that there is no problem with the OP's code and the question should be closed instead?

Comment: Yes, unless I don't understand the question.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add `version` param to `FetchData` function.
This is simplest way.

```
function TestData(guid, version) {                    
     var data = '';
     data =  FetchData(guid, version, function (guid, msg) {
           alert(version);
           return getData(guid, msg);      
     }));        
}
```

Comment: How should that solve the problem? What makes you think `FetchData` even accepts a third argument?

Comment: If You run callback inside FetchData function then You have access to `version` variable. I dont know Your code, same think is pass this variable to callback function.

Comment: *"If You run callback inside FetchData function then You have access to version variable."* Not all! Counter example: `function FetchData(foo, cb) { cb(); }; FetchData(42, function() { alert(foo); });`. According to you, the callback should have access to `foo`. But it doesn't, it throws an error. JavaScript has **lexical** scope, not dynamic scope.

Comment: I dont understand what is Your problem. You want to send `version` variable from first triggered function, but You dont want set it as argument?

Comment: I don't have a problem. I'm just saying your proposed solution doesn't solve the issue at hand. The OP wants to access `version` inside the callback. Simply passing `version` to the function which *executes* the callback doesn't fix that issue. And frankly, there is nothing obviously wrong with the OP's code, it should work as it is.

Comment: And here is the OP's version **without your fix**: http://jsfiddle.net/cwry53pp/1/. Do you notice that it works as expected? Again: The change you proposed is not a solution to this problem. There might not even be a problem.

Comment: I saying, I dont know what is Your code, so I was added `version` variable to all functions. Why? Because You maybe usings timeouts or running other functions time by time. if it still working why code from my answer not resolve Your problem? Edit: Oh, sorry, now i see You are not author of question ; )

Comment: This is not my question. It is not my code. I'm just pointing out that your answer cannot solve the problem. It should be obvious to you that, after I removed the changes you proposed and code still produces the same output as before, your changes don't have any impact. I can only recommend to you to read through my comments again and maybe read a tutorial about scope and closures in JavaScript. This is my last comment, I won't be trying to convince you that what you posted can't work. Have a good day and good luck with everything else.

Comment: I dont uderstand You man. If You dont know code, i dont know why You think my solution will not works. Why You dont give answer to author, if You have read many `tutorials`? Have a good day.

Comment: when I alert version , it did not contain any value, rather it was undefined. For now I solved it by passing version inside the FetchData method but I am not happy with it. I will do some research on closures first.

Comment: If this is not satisfied solution, maybe You will rebuild code? Btw. You will paste rest of code for better suggestions.